# Why do the engine of MiG-31 spit out flame when going for afterburner?

Tags: jet-engine, fighter, mig-31

I was seeing [this image](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Russia-Air-Force/Mikoyan-Gurevich-MiG-31BM/2479279/L?qsp=eJyrVkrOzytJrSgJqSxIVbJSSsxJKs1V0lEqSCxKzC1WsqqGiHimKFkZm5lamtfWAgDBRhDj). Always we can see an abnormal flame spit out of the engine when the pilot goes for afterburner. Why?

Comment: It's totally different from F-111's fuel dump flame. Probably the afterburner is simply too cold and the fuel doesn't burn very well.

Comment: @user3528438: I wasn't also that sure. Can you elaborate an answer from your comment?

Comment: Do you mean always in the case of MiG-31, or always regardless of make/model?

Comment: @Jpe61 I just have seen in the case of MiG-31.

Comment: @user3528438 Ok but, why does it happen on the below portion of the flame?

Answer (score 2):

The thumbnail of [this video](https://youtu.be/qaop9oJ5Obg?t=138) is a little misleading (it isn't from the same video), but show the same phenomenon.  The video has a different angle from a little further behind (also at a completely different time and place I think since the thumbnail has snow), but it looks like there's just some kind of unstable transients as the afterburners engage.

[image: flames visible in the bottom of both engines of a MiG-31 as the afterburners engage for a takeoff]

It's possible that the fuel flow rate as the afterburner engages is simply too high for the airflow for a couple seconds, so there's fuel pooling and combusting as a pool of flame at the bottom of the afterburner section of the nozzle instead of getting properly mixed and burning in the exhaust stream.

[This other video](https://youtu.be/7GmMPprt5mo?t=90) also seems to show the same thing, but only visible in the right engine, and it's harder to see.  I think that supports it being some kind of transient that doesn't always occur.  Watching it frame-by-frame it might also be that the various nozzles of the afterburner (which are typically a ring of fuel nozzles around the afterburner duct) just aren't quite in-balance; I thought initially that the left engine had a flame front starting from the center (i.e. in the exhaust stream) but it's off to the left side.

[image: a different MiG-31 takeoff showing unbalanced flame during the afterburner ignition]

I haven't been able to find a video looking up the nozzle of a MiG-31 igniting its afterburner in flight; I think that would be a helpful test of my guess.

(My bona fides, since there's some speculation in this answer:  an aerospace engineering degree and a pilot's license, though I've never worked directly on jets.)

Comment: You can embed YouTube videos, I believe.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the embed won't show a specific frame, though; and, as I say, the first video has a misleading thumbnail, which is what would embed.  ...also, I always forget that you can do that, but this time I stand by not embedding them.